# Read in a vector as CV_8UC* in OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, opencv3.0

I have a 784 x 1 vector `img` that represents a noisy 28 x 28 image.

Each pixel has a grayscale value in the range [0, 255], and I want to use the function

`dst = cv2. fastNlMeansDenoising(np.reshape(img, (28, 28)), None)`

On this image. However, upon using the function I get the error

> Unsupported image format! Only CV_8UC1, CV_8UC2 and CV_8UC3 are supported in function fastNlMeansDenoising

How can I get my vector `img` into one of these proper formats using Python openCV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now, formatting using

```
img = cv2.imdecode(img, flags=0)
```

seems to work by decoding itself to a grayscale image. the function fastNlMeansDenoising, however, is quite slow.